# MYSQL index prefix applies same to COMPOSITE PRIMARY INDEXES?

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose I have a table that has defined this primary key

```sql
CREATE TABLE `my_composite_table` (
    `table_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `first_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `second_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `third_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `create_date` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `update_date` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`first_id`, `second_id`, `third_id`, `table_id`)
)
```

According to [mysql index prefix](https://orangematter.solarwinds.com/2019/02/05/the-left-prefix-index-rule/). I can query this table efficiently like this

```sql
SELECT *
FROM my_composite_table
WHERE first_id = 1 AND second_id = 2 AND third_id = 3 AND table_id = 4;
```

```sql
SELECT * FROM my_composite_table
WHERE first_id = 1 AND second_id = 2 AND third_id = 3;
```

```sql
SELECT *
FROM my_composite_table
WHERE first_id = 1 AND second_id = 2;
```

```sql
SELECT *
FROM my_composite_table
WHERE first_id = 1;
```

My question is whether this rule applies to **composite primary keys** in the same way. I want to make a query like this:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM my_composite_table
WHERE first_id = 1 AND table_id = 4;
```

Will the query use the primary key index, or do I need to create an index for just those two fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query will use the index but will scan the values where `first_id = 1`.

It is important to distinguish between two index operations.  An index lookup goes directly to a row.  An index scan will scan the rows in the index.  These can be used together.

So, in the first query, only a lookup is used.  Why?  MySQL knows that the row is unique.

In the next three queries, MySQL will lookup the first row and then scan the rows returns all the scanned rows while the first condition is true.

In the last query, MySQL will scan all the rows as in the fourth query.  But then it will do an additional filter before deciding to return the rows.  So, this is not as efficient as the first four queries.  But it might be good enough, depending on how selective the first key of the index is.

Comment: oh nicee, so it's gonna be definitely different if instead in the fourth query I query using 
`WHERE second_id = 1 AND table_id = 4;`? then in that case it might be better to create an additional index no?

Comment: @user15362695 . . . Then the query would not match the prefix.  MySQL might implement skip scans for this purpose.  You might want to check if that is sufficient.

Comment: @ Gordon Linoff lol trueee. Thank you so much!